# Why are there 4 versions of Node JS?

Tags: node.js

Why are there (as of right now) four "current" versions of NodeJS?

- 0.10.41 (Maintenance)
- 0.12.9 (LTS)
- 4.2.3 Argon (LTS)
- 5.1.1 (Stable)

According to the NodeJS [release page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/), all of those were released on December 3rd. But what is the difference? Which should I use?

Comment: They were changed at those dates.

Comment: Well yeah... obviously. But why all for *on the same day*. I see lots of hosting services that are still using 0.12.9, but that would seem much older than 5.11. To me, it seems the 0.x versions must be quite different then the 4.x or 5.x versions. So... what's that difference.

Comment: Newer versions support es6, the older ones don't. Depending on your hosting environment you may need to go with an older version (AWS EB for instance). https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## LTS vs Stable

- LTS (Long Term Support): Mature and dependable. Proven stability and a commitment to keep it that way.
- Stable: Latest features. Usable in production, but not recommended for those who don't need those features and require dependability.

## NodeJS vs IoJS

IoJS was a fork of NodeJS to update the V8 engine and bring in ES6 support. Those two communities voted to merge, and now IoJS features have been brought into Node starting with 4 which came out in September. The reason the version format changed so drastically was because they adopted IoJS's use of [semver](https://semver.org/). Versions 1 to 3 are IoJS releases. You can more or less ignore IoJS at this point.

As I mentioned, 4 is the the latest LTS release, and 5 is the latest Stable release.

## Pre-IoJS

Prior to the merge, NodeJS 0.10 was an LTS and 0.12 was Stable. Now, 0.12 is an LTS, and 0.10 is just an old version for maintenance. I don't have any facts or figures on commitments to 0.10.

## Which to use

You should consider your target audience and the environment you have available to you.

If your environment allows for NodeJS 4.x or later (i.e. if your host environment supports it), and you have no problems with dependency compatibility on that version, feel free to target the latest LTS if you are working on a production application or module where dependability and stability are paramount, or 5 if you need or can accept the latest and greatest. If you have compatibility issues with NodeJS 4 or later, use 0.12.

[More info](https://www.dynatrace.com/news/blog/all-you-need-to-know-about-node-js-4-0/).

## How to manage multiple versions of NodeJS

You may run into the issue where you installed the latest and greatest Node and your project won't work, or conversely, you need an older version installed for one project but would like to use a newer version for another.

Enter [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), which is a bash utility that lets you install and switch to different node versions either using the command line, or dropping a settings file into your project to let it automatically switch for you. Note that NVM is Linux/OSX only; See the [NVM readme](https://web.archive.org/web/20170327125732/https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.markdown) for a list of Windows-compatible analogs.

Comment: See, that's where I'm confused. What's the diff between NodeJS/IoJS and just plain old NodeJS??

Comment: Even if you don't need es6, what's wrong with using 4.x or 5.x? Why use 0.12?

Comment: Looking to deploy to OpenShift which doesn't seem to mention 4 or 5

Comment: @Markasoftware Compatibility, both with your project's dependencies and the target versions you want your module to support (if you're writing a module).

Comment: @AdamHaile I hope my answer overhaul better clarifies the situation.

Comment: @Markasoftware I did a little looking around to see how the ecosystem is since 4 hit in September, and things are looking better for moving past 0.12 unless you need it, so I updated my answer there. Originally, people were recommending to stick to 0.12 unless you specifically needed something in >= 4.

Comment: @HackedByChinese IMO, you should never use an old version of something, if there's a newer stable one

Comment: @Markasoftware I don't think it's so cut and dry. Stable =/= the most mature and dependable, and conversely, old =/= obsolete or irrelevant. It depends on the requirements of the job at hand.

Comment: @HackedByChinese I guess you must be a debian user then compared to me as an Arch Linux one

Comment: @HackedByChinese You said that Stable (node v5) is "not recommended for those who don't need those features". What are the features that v5 introduced compared to v4?

Comment: @styfle [npm has been upgraded to v3 in Node.js v5.0.0, which (amongst other changes) will install dependencies as flat as possible in node_modules. v5.0.0 also comes with V8 4.6, which ships the new.target and spread operator JavaScript language features.](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/community/node-v5/)